# TFS 2015: Publish artifact - "A task was canceled"

Tags: tfs

Since shortly, I receive "A task was canceled" when running the build task "Publish artifact". The tfs Server is running for a view weeks now and I never had problems with these tasks.

I fixed this issue once with deleting the build output Folder but unfortunately this "workaround" is not working anymore. I tried to change the artifact name in the hope that this could change something... Nothing helped.

Log file output:

> 2016-04-22T13:04:55.6060280Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]check path :
>
> C:\agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\task.json
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]set resource file to:
>
> C:\agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\task.json
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]load strings from:
>
> C:\agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\task.json
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]load loc strings from:
>
> C:\agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\strings\resources.resjson\en-
> US\resources.resjson
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]system.hosttype=build
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]PathtoPublish=C:\agent_work\3\a
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.0896280Z ##[debug]check path : C:\agent_work\3\a
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.1052280Z ##[debug]ArtifactName=MyArtifact
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.1052280Z ##[debug]ArtifactType=Container
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.1052280Z ##[debug]TargetPath=\my\share\My Artifact\My Artifact_2.3.16113.06 2016-04-22T13:04:56.2456280Z
>
> Max Concurrent Uploads 2, Max Creators 1
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3392280Z Found 61 files to upload.
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z Files found locally 61,
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z Files evaluated 0,
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z Files left to evaluate 61.,
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z Files created without upload 0,
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z Files uploaded 0
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z Files left to process 61
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:56.3704280Z ---------------------------
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:57.7588280Z Start: UploadArtifact
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:57.7588280Z ##[error]A task was canceled.
>
> 2016-04-22T13:04:57.7588280Z End: UploadArtifact

Has anyone experienced something like this? Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot for any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the same task once more and removing the "Always Run" check, I got a useful error message:

> TF30042: The log file for the database is full. Contact your Team
>   Foundation Server ************ to back up the transaction log for the
>   database to free up some log space. Server: TheServer, Error: 9002,
>   Message: 'The transaction log for database 'Tfs_DefaultCollection' is
>   full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.'.

That solved the case.

Comment: I have the same issue, but was not able to solve it yet. How exactly did you got the above error message. Have you added a second "Publish Artifact" step? Or have you replaced the old one with a new one?

Comment: I think I just added a second "Publish Artifact" step. Although it could be that in the quest of solving the problem, I did some more steps without actually knowing. But as the error message I got indicates a crucial problem like file size, disk space or something like that - did you check your tfs server? Looks everything ok? Can you execute the task in a smaller (sandbox) project? Is there perhaps even something in the event log? Sorry, unfortunately just guess work on my side. Good luck! If I can remember anything more, I'll come back here.