# TFS (vNext) build randomly fails in step 'Publish Artifacts'

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Since some time already, our TFS 2015 builds fail randomly in *Publish Artifacts* step. The upload starts properly and after some uploaded files the process stops with this message: **##[error]A task was canceled.** (see below).

Normally we can work around that issue by simply re-queue another build. However this is annoying and contradict the idea of CI/CD.

The generic error message give me no clue where to look for the problem. Any ideas?

```
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z Files found locally 1772, 
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z Files evaluated 1772, 
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z Files left to evaluate 0., 
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z Files created without upload 0, 
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z Files uploaded 796 
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z Files left to process 976 
  2016-10-26T12:47:47.8071677Z --------------------------- 
  2016-10-26T12:47:49.0421524Z Start: UploadArtifact 
  2016-10-26T12:47:49.0577804Z ##[error]A task was canceled. 
  2016-10-26T12:47:49.0577804Z End: UploadArtifact
```

### Update

As proposed by @Patrick-MSFT, I enabled **system.debug** and got some more error details:

```
   ---------------------------
   Files found locally 1852,
   Files evaluated 1852,
   Files left to evaluate 0.,
   Files created without upload 0,
   Files uploaded 1316
   Files left to process 536
   ---------------------------
   Start: UploadArtifact
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   End: UploadArtifact
   ******************************************************************************
   Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts
   ******************************************************************************
   System.Exception: Task PublishBuildArtifacts failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
   ******************************************************************************
   Finishing Build
   ******************************************************************************
   Worker Worker-89de22b8-0ad4-4541-ad73-a758c9783464 finished running job 89de22b8-0ad4-4541-ad73-a758c9783464
```

Comment: What is the probability of the fail build ? And did this error only occurs for this special build definition?

Comment: Roughly estimated the build fails in one of five builds. And I observe this problem only on this particular build. However this build is the one which generates the most files, and which is build most often.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794888/tfs-2015-publish-artifact-a-task-was-canceled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by simply updating the build agent to the latest version. The old version in use was 1.105.7. Now I updated to 2.105.6.

Answer (score 0):

For the troubleshooting with a special build task, you can try this：

1. On the variables tab, add **system.debug** and set it to **true**. Select to
   allow at queue time.
2. In the explorer tab, view your completed build and click the build
   step to view its output.

The control options arguments described above can also be useful when you're trying to isolate a problem.

Please double check if you have set the **Timeout** in Control options of 'Publish Artifacts' which stands for this task in minutes. This may  cause the fail.

And also create a new  build definition with the same settings and try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have enabled system.debug and got some more error details (see update in question). It seems setting the timeout is not available in Control Options (we are using TFS 2015.3).

Comment: I also get this error. I don't see the Timeout options either.