# Task Publish build artifact on AppCenter endeds with error: The operation was canceled

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, visual-studio-app-center

I am using `AppCenter` to build a native swift project. All Tasks finished successfully but this task Publish build artifacts was canceled. The total time of running the build is 30 min.

Note: The Xcode build task took the majority of the time, about 20 min.

**Log file:**

```
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3210420Z ##[section]Starting: Publish symbols
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3220340Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3220730Z Task         : Publish build artifacts
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3221110Z Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3221440Z Version      : 1.186.0
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3221720Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3222130Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts
2021-05-05T11:53:45.3222600Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-05T11:53:46.1512350Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
2021-05-05T11:53:46.1512710Z Uploading 26 files
2021-05-05T11:53:46.1513090Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session f62e9ec7-5c5f-48de-8ac9-7d4f95d3f00d
2021-05-05T11:53:51.2580070Z Total file: 26 ---- Processed file: 10 (38%)
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9487670Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9488070Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9488440Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9488790Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9489150Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9489500Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9489820Z [] Try 1/3, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9490240Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9490600Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9490960Z [PutChunksAsync] Try 1/1, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9491280Z [] Try 1/3, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9491760Z File upload has been cancelled during upload file: '/Users/runner/work/1/a/symbols/Realm.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Realm'.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9492420Z File upload has been cancelled during upload file: '/Users/runner/work/1/a/symbols/Moya.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Moya'.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9493070Z File error 'The operation was canceled.' when uploading file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/symbols/Realm.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Realm'.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9493730Z File error 'The operation was canceled.' when uploading file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/symbols/Moya.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Moya'.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9494860Z ##[section]Async Command End: Upload Artifact
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9573780Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2021-05-05T11:53:54.9591680Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish symbols
```

Why the task was canceled, is it due to a long time on the build, or it is related to access right, or is it a bug, or something else. Please advise.

Comment: Which agent you are using? Private agent or hosted agent? If you are using private agent, have you checked the amount of free disk space? According to the log, it seems it processed 38%. And if you are using TFS rather than azure devops services, you could also check the log file for the database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794888/tfs-2015-publish-artifact-a-task-was-canceled.

Comment: And if above not work for you, may I know if this issue occurred recently? And you chould share you YAML file and the debug log for this task.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I am using appcenter.ms so it is a hosed agent. I am using Azure DevOps not TFS. There is no YAML file. The above log file is for Publish symbols Task.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If you are not using YAML mode, please share the configuration of your publish symbols task in your question, so that I could check some more info.

Comment: Sir, using appcenter.ms for iOS apps doesn't allow me to control the tasks in build pipelies. Only I can set the build configuration using the online portal. Can you please advise is there is a way?

Comment: Sir, using appcenter.ms for iOS apps doesn't allow me to control the tasks in build pipelines. Only I can set the build configuration using the online portal. Can you please advise if there is a way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232027/discussion-between-adham-enaya-and-leo-liu-msft).